# How do I override physical asset paths in lithium li3

Tags: php, lithium

I'd like to override the paths lithium uses to retrieve assets but am not sure how to do that.

Using the [Media::assets](http://li3.me/docs/lithium/net/http/Media::assets()) method doesn't seem to have any affect accept that it changes the Url that the [Html::script](http://li3.me/docs/lithium/template/helper/Html::script) helper uses.

How do I appropriately override the **real path** that lithium uses for assets? Below is an example of how I tried to override the asset paths for javascript files:

```
Media::assets('js', array(
    'suffix' => '.js',
    'filter' => null,
    'theme' => 'blue',
    'paths' => array(
        '{:base}/{:library}/themes/{:theme}/public/js/{:path}' => array('base', 'library', 'theme', 'path'),
        '{:base}/{:library}/themes/default/public/js/{:path}' => array('base', 'library', 'path')
    )
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate more about what you mean by retrieving assets and real path?

`Media::assets` function does exactly what it is expected from it, to set the paths used by `Media::asset()` which is currently used by the default `path` handler in `lithium\template\view\Renderer`. The problem is that the default `path` handler does not seem to pass a `library` option, so my guess is the `{:library}` token will always be replaced with the basename of your default library path.

I don't see why you would need to fiddle with the default paths though. Plus you can always use absolute path by adding `/` prefix when you use `Html::script` function.